# What is the accepted method for a global state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering what would you guys consider the best way to go about having some simple stuff stored across sessions without using the DB.
I'm looking to have like having 'modes' to a website. So it can be in mode a or b, and depending on the mode, buttons would do different things.

Would using `Rails.cache.read` and `write` be the best option ? I've heard it has issues with heroku if you leave the cache as filesystem, then has problems as a memcache because of multi-threading ?

I'm really trying to avoid having a whole table on DB getting used for users checking a global state of the site each request.

Comment: Should the state be specific for an user, or for any request? In order word, if you set `a`, will all requests be in state `a` or just the requests from a specific user/client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a "global" state, then you need to create a singke dependency for each instance of your application.

In fact, you can't rely on cookies or sessions, are they are client-oriented and they are not shared between clients.

The database is the most common approach. You *may* be able to use the file system in some cases, but not for Heroku as there may be several different instances of your app running under different file systems.

Any solution that can easily be shared across instances will work:

- Memory database like Redis
- SQL or NoSQL database
- Cache systems, as long as they are not specific to one instance. Memcached may work, but it's not persistent (hence you may lose the state)
- External storage (such as Amazon S3)

To me, a relational database or a memory database such as Redis seems to be the most plausible solution.

Comment: So i ended up using the Rails cache and set it to memory instead of filesystem, because filesystem simply didnt work on heroku.

It works fine with memory, but of course when heroku brings your site down due to no one using it, it clears the memory. Not a huge deal for what im using it for, but do you by any chance of a easy suggestion of where i could store it for those moments.

I really dont feel like bringing up a whole extra process in the form of Redis just for this, maybe in the future if the project gets big enough and needs all that redis offers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want per-user setting - consider storing in session (which can be stored in cookies), or directly in cookies.
Both methods end up storing some data (but not lots of it, because cookies are passed by browser with each request) inside clients' browsers.

Comment: Would this work as a global state ? Wouldnt it be per session if its a cookie.

Comment: That will be per session, missed that you wanted a state for all users at once

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a table - just so that you have it, but then make the value available via the ApplicationContoller, with a simple cache method in between

so something like: -  not tested!!

```
def get_mode
  if @mode_timeout.nil? or @mode_timeout < Time.now
    @mode = ModeModel.first.mode
    @mode_timeout = Time.now + 60.seconds
  end
  @mode
end
```

You'll have to create a model, or you could update if via a controller with a set_mode method instead, but that would be more transient.

Then you can just call get_mode from your controller.